# Data type mismatch in criteria expression error using listview

Tags: vb.net

I get a `Data type mismatch` in criteria expression. I am trying to update the quantity after making a sale.

I have used this code on another program and it works perfect. I've gone over the code a lot of times and it seems OK.

```
For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
    con.Open()

    Dim cb2 As String = "update tblProduct set Quantity = Quantity - " & CInt(ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text) & " where product_code= " & CInt(ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text) & ""


    cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb2)

    cmd.Connection = con


    cmd.ExecuteReader()
    con.Close()
Next
```

Comment: Do the subitems contain what you think they do? You may be accessing the wrong subitems, or at least one subitem contains values that are *not* integers

Comment: they both are integers

Comment: What EXACTLY does `cb2` contain?  That's where the data type mismatch is so that's what we need to see.  By the way, what's the point of using `CInt` when you're then converting the `Integers` back to `Strings` again?

Comment: What is the type of the `product_code` column in the database?

Comment: thanks guys....found the problem...my product_code in the data base was a string and i was converting it to integer...thanks again